# Why would _sent dataview table have subsciberIDs not in the subsciber table?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm working on SFMC, been struggling to join subscriber table and sent table on subscriberID, I also tried subsciberkey. It turns out all entries in sent dataview have subscriberID (and subscriberkey) that are not in subscriber table...

Not sure how to take a closer look at why this is or how the sent DV table is generated and whats different to how the subscriber table is generated.

any help/tips would be great.

Comment: are you in a child bu, if so use ent._subscriber

Comment: Hi. Thank for the response. ent._subscribers seems to just be a  short list of test account emails, not those connected the _sent table